# MageUI successfully creates a manifest but mage.exe creates an invalid file

Tags: c#, .net, mage, mageui

I'm replacing a dll needed by the application with an updated version.  Then I need to update the application manifest.  When using the UI, the application will run.  The commandline creates an invalid manifest.

Scenario:
clickonce application is structured as follows:
-Directory (containing full application)
--clickonceApp.application
--VersionDirectory (Versioned Folder)
---clickonceApp.manifest
---dlls

1. Replace dll file
2. From within VersionDirectory, Run mage.exe -update clickonceApp.manifest -FromDirectory .
3. From Directory, Run mage.exe -update clickonceApp.application -appmanifest .\VersionDirectory\clickonceApp.manifest
4. Application wont launch due to: The element 'dependentAssembly' in namespace 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2' has invalid child element 'hash' in namespace 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2'. List of possible elements expected: 'assemblyIdentity' in namespace 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2'.
5. Launch MageUI (using the same mage.exe)
6. Open clickonceApp.manifest
7. On the files tab, click populate
8. click save and accept the unsigned warning
9. From Directory, Run mage.exe -update clickonceApp.application -appmanifest .\VersionDirectory\clickonceApp.manifest
10. The application launches successfully

Why is there a difference between mage and mageui?
Open existing manifest

Comment: This is the version of mage I'm using: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\mage.exe

Comment: I have encountered this issue as well and would like to know what the resolution could be? I am currently using a workaround.